# Porting a linker script from STM32F1 to STM32F2

Tags: stm32, linker-script

I am trying to port [PyMite](http://code.google.com/p/python-on-a-chip/) from STM32F1 to STM32F2. One of the files that I am assuming must be changed is called `stm32f10x.ld`. I have looked around for an equivalent of this (called `stm32f2xx.ld`?) but haven't found anything.

I'm now thinking that I should maybe port "by hand" the linker script. Below is the original linker script. What kind of changes should I be making to have it work for STM32F2?

```
MEMORY
{
    sram (W!RX) : ORIGIN = 0x20000000, LENGTH = 64k
    flash (RX) : ORIGIN = 0x08000000, LENGTH = 512k
}

SECTIONS
{  
    .text :
    {
        . = ALIGN(4);
        _text = .;
        PROVIDE(stext = .);
        KEEP(*(.isr_vector))
        KEEP(*(.init))
        *(.text .text.*)        
        *(.rodata .rodata.*)        
        *(.gnu.linkonce.t.*)
        *(.glue_7)
        *(.glue_7t)
        *(.gcc_except_table)
        *(.gnu.linkonce.r.*)
        . = ALIGN(4);
        _etext = .;
        _sidata = _etext;
        PROVIDE(etext = .);   
            _fini = . ;
                *(.fini)

    } >flash

    .data : AT (_etext)
    {
        . = ALIGN(4);
        _sdata = .;
        *(.ramfunc .ramfunc.* .fastrun .fastrun.*)
        *(.data .data.*)
        *(.gnu.linkonce.d.*)
        . = ALIGN(4);
        _edata = .;
    } >sram

        .ARM.extab :
        {
            *(.ARM.extab*)
        } >sram

        __exidx_start = .;
        .ARM.exidx :
        {
            *(.ARM.exidx*)
        } >sram
        __exidx_end = .;

    .bss (NOLOAD) : {
        . = ALIGN(4);
        /* This is used by the startup in order to initialize the .bss secion */
        _sbss = .;
        *(.bss .bss.*)
        *(.gnu.linkonce.b.*)
        *(COMMON)
        . = ALIGN(4);        
        _ebss = .;
    } >sram

    end = .;
    PROVIDE( _estack = 0x20010000 );
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most Chip "families" use a similar memory layout, so it might "just work" without changes.

There are only 2 interseting things in this script:

```
MEMORY
{
    sram (W!RX) : ORIGIN = 0x20000000, LENGTH = 64k
    flash (RX) : ORIGIN = 0x08000000, LENGTH = 512k
}
```

The `MEMORY` section needs to be checked agains datasheet/reference manual whether the addresses and sizes of the SRAM and FLASH are correct.

The other point is the stack end `_estack`, as it is hardcoded:

`PROVIDE( _estack = 0x20010000 );`

You might have noticed that this is the "end of SRAM", as `0x20000000 + 64k` is exactly
`0x20010000`. You might need to change this accordingly.

Comment: IIRC the STMF32 has fairly different register maps and changes to vector table also, so be ready to make more changes...